# Share preprocessor macros across c++ and glsl code?

Tags: c++, macros, glsl, c-preprocessor

I'm setting up lighting for an openGL program. I'd like to be able to easily tweak the number of lighting sources in C++ without having to touch my shader

In my C++ code:

```
#define NUM_LIGHTS 5
GLfloat lightposn [4 * NUM_LIGHTS];
```

In my glsl code:

```
 uniform vec4 lightposn[NUM_LIGHTS];
```

How can I pass this NUM_LIGHTS value to my shader? Is it possible to use a macro defined in a c++ file in a shader? Is there another easy way to set NUM_LIGHTS across both my c++ code and my glsl code?

Comment: How is your shader stored ? On disk, or as a string in your source code?

Comment: In its own file on disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the header file with the `#defines` in it into a string, and 'prepend' it to the shader by passing it to `glShaderSource` first

```
char *shader_src[3];
shader_src[0] = "#version ...\n";
shader_src[1] = ReadHeaderFile(....);
shader_src[2] = ReadShaderSourceFile(....);
glShaderSource(shader, 3, shader_src, NULL);
...compile, link, and check for errors...
```

Comment: That will break, as there would/should be a [`#version`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Version) directive, in the top of the Shader Source File, and the `#version` directive has to be the first thing. Unless you actually suggest to put the `#version` directive in the Header File as well?

Comment: @Vallentin: As long as the header contains just #defines, it should be fine (#version just has to be before any declarations and definitions, not preprocessor stuff).  If you really need to, you can put the `#version` in its own source string.

Comment: No that's not true, it shouldn't. The GLSL specification explicitly says "The #version directive must occur in a shader before anything else, except for comments and white space".

Comment: @vallentin: `#define`s themselves expand to whitespace (per the C preprocessor spec), so may occur before the `#version`

Comment: How do I do the step `...compile, link, and check for errors...`? How can I run the preprocessor manually? Or can I even do that programmatically somehow? And what do you mean by `link`? (Sorry, I'm a noob when it comes to OpenGL shaders.)

Comment: @HelloGoodbye `glCompileShader` to compile, `glLinkProgram` to link, `glGetShaderInfoLog` and `glGetProgramInfoLog` to see errors/warnings.